# How to exact match a string by taking previous and next word into consideration

Tags: java, regex, xml, string

I am new to `java regex`.So, I have a `xml` file which contains different nodes. file is  -

```
<Node id="855"/>PROFILE<Node id="862"/>:<Node id="863"/>
<Node id="864"/>8<Node id="865"/> <Node id="866"/>years<Node id="871"/> <Node id="872"/>IT<Node id="874"/> <Node id="875"/>industry<Node id="883"/> <Node id="884"/>experience<Node id="894"/> <Node id="895"/>in<Node id="897"/> <Node id="898"/>web<Node id="901"/> <Node id="902"/>based<Node id="907"/> <Node id="908"/>applications<Node id="920"/> <Node id="921"/>that<Node id="925"/> <Node id="926"/>involved<Node id="934"/> <Node id="935"/>extensive<Node id="944"/> <Node id="945"/>development<Node id="956"/> <Node id="957"/>work<Node id="961"/> <Node id="962"/>in<Node id="964"/> <Node id="965"/>Java<Node id="969"/>/<Node id="970"/>J<Node id="971"/>2<Node id="972"/>EE<Node id="974"/>,<Node id="975"/>Jquery<Node id="981"/>,<Node id="982"/>Jqgrid<Node id="988"/>,<Node id="989"/>Ajax<Node id="993"/>.<Node id="994"/>
<Node id="995"/>Good<Node id="999"/> <Node id="1000"/>experience<Node id="1010"/> <Node id="1011"/>in<Node id="1013"/> <Node id="1014"/>agile<Node id="1019"/> <Node id="1020"/>methodology<Node id="1031"/> <Node id="1032"/>.<Node id="1033"/>
```

I have a string which I need to match with this string .

```
PROFILE:
8 years IT industry experience in web based applications that involved extensive development work in Java/J2EE,Jquery,Jqgrid,Ajax.
```

So,

```
private void parseXml(ArrayList<String> elements, String filePath) {
    boolean flag = false;
    String nextId = "0";
    String xmlData = getTextWithNodesDataFromXml(filePath);
    for (String s : elements) {
        System.out.println(s);
        String token;
        int id;
        String regex = "";
        if (flag == false) {
            regex = "<Node id=\"([0-9]+)\"\\/>(" + s + ")";
            flag = true;
            Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(xmlData);
            if (matcher1.find()) {
                System.out.println("match found -->" + s);
            }
        }
```

SO first argument is an array list which contains tokens of the string which is to be matched and second is the path of the file. `xmlData` is with the nodes I mentioned earlier, with which I need to match. So If I found `PROFILE` is matching three times then How Can I check the entire string ? I have to match the exact string with this nodes ? How can I do that?

Comment: I am confused by the "taking previous and next word into consideration" in the title.  Also by use of word "profile".  Can you add several different inputs and say what output you expect?  Are you returning true/false if it matches, or finding the location in the nodes file where the sentence (elements) starts?

Comment: Yes, I want to find the id's of nodes from where the sentence starts and ends . Basically, I want start and end offset.

Comment: @hack_on I mean that file can contain profile word many times right. But after profile word remaining string should be the same.So, If we found profile three times and after first profile next thing is not : and which is something else, so, I want to exact match the whole string.

Comment: I have updated my answer to deal with multiple profiles in one file and to extract the start and end ids.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to compare comparable things: the XML you shown is a tokenization of sentences. You try to compare it to a whole String.

If you transform the XML into an array of String and tokenize the sentence PROFILE by `String.split("\\s+")`, then you have to compare two arrays of String.

Perhaps, an exact match isn't you want?

In this case you have to compute a percentage of resemblance `p`, decide a threshold `t` and keep only the PROFILE with `p > t`.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some assumptions about what is being requested and created a working solution as I can best understand it.

I cheated by avoiding reading files.

```
package stacktest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StringMatch 
{
    private String getTextWithNodesDataFromXml(String filePath)
    {
        // cheating here by passing the xml as a string in.
        return filePath;
    }

    private int []  findMatches(List<String> elements, String filePath) 
    {
        String xmlData = getTextWithNodesDataFromXml(filePath);

        String outerRegex = "(<Node id=\"[0-9]+\"\\/>PROFILE<Node id=\"[0-9]+\"\\/>:<)";
        Pattern outerPattern = Pattern.compile(outerRegex, Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher outerMatcher = outerPattern.matcher(xmlData);
        int outerMatches = 0;
        boolean first = true;
        int lastStart=0;
        ArrayList<String> profiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (outerMatcher.find())
        {
            String localXML = outerMatcher.group(1);
            int startIndex = outerMatcher.start(1);

            if (!first)
            {
                localXML = xmlData.substring(lastStart, startIndex);
                profiles.add(localXML);
            }
            lastStart = startIndex;
            first = false;
            outerMatches++;
        }
        // Is there a hanging one at the end?
        if (outerMatches > 0)
        {
            String localXML = xmlData.substring(lastStart);
            profiles.add(localXML);
        }

        for (String profile: profiles)
        {
            // System.out.println(localXML);
            String regex = "<Node id=\"([0-9]+)\"\\/>([^<]+)";

            Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(profile);
            ArrayList<String> toMatch = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> idMatch = new ArrayList<String>();

            while (matcher1.find())
            {
                String token = matcher1.group(2);
                toMatch.add(token);
                String id = matcher1.group(1);
                idMatch.add(id);
                outerMatches++;
            }

            if (elements.size() == toMatch.size())
            {
                boolean didFind = true;
                for (int i=0; i< elements.size(); i++) 
                {
                    String element = elements.get(i);
                    String match = toMatch.get(i);
                    if (!element.equals(match))
                    {
                        didFind = false;
                    }
                }

                if (didFind)
                {
                    int[] toReturn = new int[2];
                    toReturn[0] = Integer.parseInt(idMatch.get(0));
                    toReturn[1] = Integer.parseInt(idMatch.get(idMatch.size()-1));
                    return toReturn;
                }
            }

        }

        return null;
     }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String nodes = "<Node id=\"855\"/>PROFILE<Node id=\"862\"/>:<Node id=\"863\"/>\n" +
                "<Node id=\"864\"/>8<Node id=\"865\"/> <Node id=\"866\"/>years<Node id=\"871\"/> <Node id=\"872\"/>IT<Node id=\"874\"/> <Node id=\"875\"/>industry<Node id=\"883\"/> <Node id=\"884\"/>experience<Node id=\"894\"/> <Node id=\"895\"/>in<Node id=\"897\"/> <Node id=\"898\"/>web<Node id=\"901\"/> <Node id=\"902\"/>based<Node id=\"907\"/> <Node id=\"908\"/>applications<Node id=\"920\"/> <Node id=\"921\"/>that<Node id=\"925\"/> <Node id=\"926\"/>involved<Node id=\"934\"/> <Node id=\"935\"/>extensive<Node id=\"944\"/> <Node id=\"945\"/>development<Node id=\"956\"/> <Node id=\"957\"/>work<Node id=\"961\"/> <Node id=\"962\"/>in<Node id=\"964\"/> <Node id=\"965\"/>Java<Node id=\"969\"/>/<Node id=\"970\"/>J<Node id=\"971\"/>2<Node id=\"972\"/>EE<Node id=\"974\"/>,<Node id=\"975\"/>Jquery<Node id=\"981\"/>,<Node id=\"982\"/>Jqgrid<Node id=\"988\"/>,<Node id=\"989\"/>Ajax<Node id=\"993\"/>.<Node id=\"994\"/>\n" +
                "<Node id=\"995\"/>Good<Node id=\"999\"/> <Node id=\"1000\"/>experience<Node id=\"1010\"/>";

        String nodes2 = "<Node id=\"855\"/>PROFILE<Node id=\"862\"/>:<Node id=\"863\"/>\n" +
                "<Node id=\"864\"/>8<Node id=\"865\"/> <Node id=\"866\"/>years<Node id=\"871\"/> <Node id=\"872\"/>IT<Node id=\"874\"/> <Node id=\"875\"/>industry<Node id=\"883\"/> <Node id=\"884\"/>experience<Node id=\"894\"/> <Node id=\"895\"/>in<Node id=\"897\"/> <Node id=\"898\"/>web<Node id=\"901\"/> <Node id=\"902\"/>based<Node id=\"907\"/> <Node id=\"908\"/>applications<Node id=\"920\"/> <Node id=\"921\"/>that<Node id=\"925\"/> <Node id=\"926\"/>involved<Node id=\"934\"/> <Node id=\"935\"/>extensive<Node id=\"944\"/> <Node id=\"945\"/>development<Node id=\"956\"/> <Node id=\"957\"/>work<Node id=\"961\"/> <Node id=\"962\"/>in<Node id=\"964\"/> <Node id=\"965\"/>Java<Node id=\"969\"/>/<Node id=\"970\"/>J<Node id=\"971\"/>2<Node id=\"972\"/>EE<Node id=\"974\"/>,<Node id=\"975\"/>Jquery<Node id=\"981\"/>,<Node id=\"982\"/>Jqgrid<Node id=\"988\"/>,<Node id=\"989\"/>Ajax<Node id=\"993\"/>.<Node id=\"994\"/>";
                //"<Node id=\"995\"/>Good<Node id=\"999\"/> <Node id=\"1000\"/>experience<Node id=\"1010\"/>";

        String nodes3 = "<Node id=\"1\"/>PROFILE<Node id=\"2\"/>:<Node id=\"3\"/>This<Node id=\"4\"/>is<Node id=\"5\"/>not<Node id=\"6\"/>the<Node id=\"7\"/>Profile<Node id=\"8\"/>\n" +
                "<Node id=\"855\"/>PROFILE<Node id=\"862\"/>:<Node id=\"863\"/>\n" +
                "<Node id=\"864\"/>8<Node id=\"865\"/> <Node id=\"866\"/>years<Node id=\"871\"/> <Node id=\"872\"/>IT<Node id=\"874\"/> <Node id=\"875\"/>industry<Node id=\"883\"/> <Node id=\"884\"/>experience<Node id=\"894\"/> <Node id=\"895\"/>in<Node id=\"897\"/> <Node id=\"898\"/>web<Node id=\"901\"/> <Node id=\"902\"/>based<Node id=\"907\"/> <Node id=\"908\"/>applications<Node id=\"920\"/> <Node id=\"921\"/>that<Node id=\"925\"/> <Node id=\"926\"/>involved<Node id=\"934\"/> <Node id=\"935\"/>extensive<Node id=\"944\"/> <Node id=\"945\"/>development<Node id=\"956\"/> <Node id=\"957\"/>work<Node id=\"961\"/> <Node id=\"962\"/>in<Node id=\"964\"/> <Node id=\"965\"/>Java<Node id=\"969\"/>/<Node id=\"970\"/>J<Node id=\"971\"/>2<Node id=\"972\"/>EE<Node id=\"974\"/>,<Node id=\"975\"/>Jquery<Node id=\"981\"/>,<Node id=\"982\"/>Jqgrid<Node id=\"988\"/>,<Node id=\"989\"/>Ajax<Node id=\"993\"/>.<Node id=\"994\"/>" +
                "PROFILE<Node id=\"1021\"/>:<Node id=\"1022\"/>This<Node id=\"1023\"/>is<Node id=\"1024\"/>not<Node id=\"1025\"/>the<Node id=\"1026\"/>Profile<Node id=\"1027\"/>\n";

        String[] el = { "PROFILE", ":", "\n",
                        "8", " ", "years", " ", "IT", " ", "industry", " ", "experience", " ", "in", " ", "web",
                        " ", "based", " ", "applications", " ", "that", " ", "involved", " ", "extensive", " ", 
                        "development", " ", "work", " ", "in", " ", "Java", "/", "J", "2", "EE", ",", "Jquery", 
                        ",", "Jqgrid", ",", "Ajax", "."
                        };

        List<String> elements =  Arrays.asList(el);

        StringMatch sm = new StringMatch();
        printTest(sm.findMatches(elements, nodes)); 
        printTest(sm.findMatches(elements, nodes2)); 
        printTest(sm.findMatches(elements, nodes3)); 
    }

    private static void printTest(int[] vals)
    {
        if (vals != null) 
        {
            System.out.println("found match from id: " + vals[0] + " to " + vals[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("no match");
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    }

}
```

There are three test calls to the method and they return:

```
no match
--------------------------------
found match from id: 855 to 993
--------------------------------
found match from id: 855 to 993
--------------------------------
```